# Convert DLT logs to any of these file formats (.txt or .csv) using Python in Windows

Tags: python, diagnostic-tools

I have adb device connected to Windows PC over USB -> currently I am doing the following in a manual way but I would like to automate the following using Python in Windows environment:

1. Open DLT Viewer and connect to the ECU / or in the background also
   it is fine
2. When I send a start command using Python (how to api required) It
   should start logging all the log file into a .txt or .csv file
3. When I send a stop command (how to api required) it should stop
   logging all the content in the file and should save in the
   predefined path
4. Then text search to find whether the payload/app id/Ct ID with
   expected value (I will define for different scenarios) - and return
   whether the particular payload is present or not.